# Total memory is lower than what I actually have

Tags: linux, memory, 64-bit, arch-linux

uname -a : `Linux amro 5.1.14-arch1-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Sat Jun 22 16:28:48 UTC 2019 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

I bought a single 8gb ram stick, but KSysGuard says that it's a total of 5.8gb.

/proc/meminfo says that it's 6gb

```
MemTotal:        6113940 kB
```

free -m

```
             total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           5970        1832        2567         151        1569        3709
Swap:          1023           0        1023
```

However, dmidecode says the correct values

dmidecode -t Memory

```
# dmidecode 3.2
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 2.8 present.

Handle 0x000F, DMI type 16, 23 bytes
Physical Memory Array
    Location: System Board Or Motherboard
    Use: System Memory
    Error Correction Type: None
    Maximum Capacity: 256 GB
    Error Information Handle: 0x000E
    Number Of Devices: 2

Handle 0x0016, DMI type 17, 40 bytes
Memory Device
    Array Handle: 0x000F
    Error Information Handle: 0x0015
    Total Width: 64 bits
    Data Width: 64 bits
    Size: 8192 MB
    Form Factor: DIMM
    Set: None
    Locator: DIMM 0
    Bank Locator: P0 CHANNEL A
    Type: DDR4
    Type Detail: Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered)
    Speed: 2133 MT/s
    Manufacturer: Unknown
    Serial Number: 00000000
    Asset Tag: Not Specified
    Part Number: CMK8GX4M1D3000C16   
    Rank: 1
    Configured Memory Speed: 1067 MT/s
    Minimum Voltage: 1.2 V
    Maximum Voltage: 1.2 V
    Configured Voltage: 1.2 V
```

Is this normal? Or is there something wrong with my ram stick? Thanks for the help.

**MORE INFO**

dmidecode -t baseboard

```
# dmidecode 3.2
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 2.8 present.

Handle 0x0002, DMI type 2, 15 bytes
Base Board Information
    Manufacturer: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd.
    Product Name: B450M GAMING PLUS (MS-7B87)
    Version: 1.0
    Serial Number: J216413997
    Asset Tag: To be filled by O.E.M.
    Features:
        Board is a hosting board
        Board is replaceable
    Location In Chassis: To be filled by O.E.M.
    Chassis Handle: 0x0003
    Type: Motherboard
    Contained Object Handles: 0

Handle 0x0033, DMI type 41, 11 bytes
Onboard Device
    Reference Designation: Broadcom 5762
    Type: Ethernet
    Status: Enabled
    Type Instance: 1
    Bus Address: 0000:16:00.0

Handle 0x0034, DMI type 41, 11 bytes
Onboard Device
    Reference Designation: Realtek ALC898
    Type: Sound
    Status: Enabled
    Type Instance: 1
    Bus Address: 0000:38:00.6
```

(@Señor CMasMas mentioned that it could be shared graphics memory, since I am using an iGPU, I am thinking this could be the case.)

sudo dmesg | grep VRAM

```
[    3.849314] amdgpu 0000:38:00.0: VRAM: 2048M 0x000000F400000000 - 0x000000F47FFFFFFF (2048M used)
[    3.849321] [drm] Detected VRAM RAM=2048M, BAR=2048M
[    3.849438] [drm] amdgpu: 2048M of VRAM memory ready
```

Comment: Can you post what motherboard you have? `dmidecode -t baseboard`

Comment: No problem, updated above question to include info

Comment: 2GB for shared graphics memory?  Some things will show it as gone from the other memory, some wont.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas Is there a way to check whether it's being used for graphics? This could be the case since I am using an iGPU. The command `sudo dmesg | grep VRAM` will be shown above, hope that helps

Comment: I just confirmed it, you are correct! Thanks a lot, you've been a huge help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @SeñorCMasMas and @NatalieAdams for helping me figure out the issue

The problem was that the 2GB was being used for shared graphics memory. I checked this by changing the buffer size in the BIOS and making it lower.